# Azure Service Bus Topic - delays when receiving a message using the Node.js SDK

Tags: node.js, azure, servicebus

I am experimenting with the Azure Node.js SDK and Service Bus Topics using the latest available npm package - 0.10.6 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure).
I want to post a new message and receive it using the following code:

```
var azure = require('azure');

var connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://sfbustest.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={key-name};SharedAccessKey={access-key}";
var topicName = "{topic-name}";
var subscriptionName = "{subscription-name}";

var serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService(connectionString);

serviceBusService.getSubscription(topicName, subscriptionName, function(error, subscription){
        //if(error) return callback(error);
        if(!subscription){
            serviceBusService.createSubscription(topicName, subscriptionName, function (error) {
                if (error) throw error;

                postMessage_retreiveMessage(null);
            });
        } else {
            postMessage_retreiveMessage(null);
        }

    });

//postMessage_retreiveMessage();
function postMessage_retreiveMessage(){
    var topicMsg = {
        body: new Date().toISOString()
    };

    serviceBusService.sendTopicMessage(topicName, topicMsg, function (error) {
        if(error) throw error;

        console.log("message sent: ");
        console.log(topicMsg);

        var receiveOptions = { /* isPeekLock: true, */ timeoutIntervalInS: 30 };

        serviceBusService.receiveSubscriptionMessage(topicName, subscriptionName, receiveOptions, function(error, receivedMessage){
            if(error) throw error;

            console.log("message received: ");
            console.log(receivedMessage);
        });
    });
}
```

The Issue: 
When the Topic is created and **partitioning is enable** - which is default if a topic is created through the Management Portal - 
in that case, I experience huge delays before the message is finally received.

This behaviour is not reproducible with the .NET SDK though.

Also, if **Partitioning is switched off** then I don't experience any significant delays any more and the behaviour is no longer reproducible as well.

Looking into the Azure SDK for Node.js I noticed a call to the following end-point is made (when receiveSubscriptionMessage is invoked):

```
https://sfbustest.servicebus.windows.net:443/{topic-name}/Subscriptions/{subscription-name}/Messages/Head?timeout=30&api-version=2013-10.
```

Its documentation is available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780770.aspx.
In the introduction section of the documentation it is stated that the HTTP API supports partitioned entities: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798895.aspx.

If I manually call that end-point, with Fiddler for example, I observe the described delays as well.

I would very much appreciate if someone could help me understand what is causing the behavior.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to [Use sessions with partitioned entities](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-bus/service-bus-partitioning.md#use-sessions-with-partitioned-entities). 
In my test, after adding the `sessionId` in message, the delays drop to 2 sec in average.

E.G.

```
 var topicMsg = {
        body: new Date().toISOString(),
        brokerProperties:{
            SessionId:'mysession'
        }
    };
```

Comment: FYI, you’ll have a better experience reading the documentation on Azure.com instead of GitHub: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/service-bus-partitioning/#use-sessions-with-partitioned-entities

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the older `azure-sb` package that relies on the HTTP REST apis. I would recommend using the newer `@azure/service-bus` package which uses the faster AMQP implementation and does not have the call going out that you have found to cause delays

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply, but just in case someone is running into issues with the older service-bus node SDK and landed here, refer to the links below.

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus`(based on AMQP - which is faster/better performant) has been published.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)